# How to set HostingStartupAssembliesKey in a ASP.NET Core WebApplication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft.extensions.hosting, asp.net-core-minimal-hosting-model

I want to declare a custom DLL as "hosting startup assembly" in an ASP.NET Core 7.0 web application. This is explained here, but unfortunately I cannot implement it for WebApplication.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/platform-specific-configuration?view=aspnetcore-7.0#specify-the-hosting-startup-assembly

The sample code given there shows this for IHostBuilder, but I need a WebApplicationBuilder. Can this also be done for web applications with the new "minimal hosting model"?

I'm afraid this is not possible or is there a way to set the HostingStartupAssembliesKey in the new ["minimal hosting model" of ASP.NET as of 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#new-hosting-model)? As you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-7.0#change-the-content-root-app-name-and-environment), the new WebApplicationOptions class doesn't offer any way to do this.

I want to explicitly specify the hosting-startup-assembly in the code, with an environment variable (ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES) everything already works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't supported by `WebApplicationBuilder`, but, as an official workaround, you can just set the environment variable in code before creating the `WebApplicationBuilder`:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(
    $"ASPNETCORE_{WebHostDefaults.HostingStartupAssembliesKey}", 
    "[ASSEMBLY_HERE]");

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

Reference: [Modify startup assemblies using the minimal hosting model](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38765).